# Flexbox two divs next each other and responsive

Tags: html, css

I am creating an Layout for my project and I am working with Flexbox (see image and css style). Well it seems to be working but not for mobile. For example if I resise the screen then the columns will be resize but the right column (Map) is not jumping below the content. How can I do it?

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"><h1>HEADER</h1></div>
  <div class="main">
      <div class="leftSide">
          <div class="menuItem">Menu Item</div>
          <div class="secondItem">Content</div>
      </div>
      <div class="rightSide">
            <div class="thirdItem">Map</div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
// Layout start page
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header{
    border: 5px solid yellowgreen;
}

.main{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.leftSide{
    flex:0 0 65%;
    border: 5px solid red;

}

.rightSide{
    flex: 1;
    border: 5px solid black; 
}

.menuItem {
    border: 5px solid purple;
}
```

Comment: You need to use `@media` queries, and you'll want to look at the `flex-direction` property. By default this is `row`, but it can also be set to `column`. [This](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a great starter guide to flexbox.

Comment: Add a media query in your CSS to target the screen size you want the items to wrap. Then use `flex-direction: row` to display items vertically

Comment: @Jackson, I think you mean `flex-direction: column`.

Comment: Ok, I thought there is a trick. Then I will use @media I guess then I also need to adjust the leftSide within media

Comment: @NoahTony if my answer below helped you, I'd appreciate it if you accepted it as the correct answer :) --- if you still need help, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS, change the width to whatever you need.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
.main{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-direction: column
  }
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XPmMdQ